# Trouble comparing images for a memory match game (Java)

Tags: java

I am looking for some basic advice on how I can accomplish this goal. I created an array list of images (2 of each image), but I am having trouble figuring out how I could determine if 2 images are a match. So if you guys can tell me what information I am missing or the basic steps on how I would accomplish comparing two images in an Array list, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom class around your image, you could determine whether they match in a bunch of different ways.

So, rather than having this:

```
ArrayList<BufferedImage> imageList;
```

You'd want something like

```
ArrayList<MemoryCard> cardList;
```

where `MemoryCard` has:

```
BufferedImage image;
//some way to identify this card. 
//Most would use an enum, but you could assign unique ints, Strings, or some other 
//    Object as well if you wanted.

public boolean isMatching(MemoryCard otherCard)
{
    //if (identifierField == otherCard.identifierField)
    //    return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then, when they pull up two cards just check `isMatching` to see if they are a match.

---

It may be worth mentioning that every `Object` in Java has the `equals` method which is used for a similar purpose. (*To see whether "this" Object **is** "that" Object*). Another approach might be to override this method on your class. However, this could impact some functionality in your ArrayList and other Collections, especially hash-based implementations if you don't also override `hashcode`.

If you do want to override `equals`, make sure you know what that may affect elsewhere in your code. (*Googling more about "Java equals" will come up with much better information than I could make fit here*)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed.